# Issue with Multiple/Distributed hibernate SessionFactory instances with MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, distributed-caching, sessionfactory, database-engine

I am having an issue while accessing single database instance using multiple/distributed Hibernate SessionFactories i.e. multiple instances of Hibernate SessionFactory.
If I use one session factory to perform insert operation and create new SessionFactory to retrieve data from database without closing the former SessionFactory then I get "null".
I have also tried to use multiple Second Level Cache Platforms but none resolved issues.
Do reply if anyone have found any solution to this.

I am using MySql database and my the database engine chosen at installation time is Innodb.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working over the issue and trying everything which could be done with hibernate I found no solutions to the issue.
Then after I tried changing the database engine to MYISAM from the earlier Innodb which resolved issues of data not getting fetched and throwing NullPointerException.

I would like to know if somebody can tell why MYISAM worked and Innodb failed to work in distributed operations for insert followed by retrieval ?

Answer (score 0):

MyISAM by default make autocommi=true.
MYISAM is a pretty old engine. It is advisable to use INNODb storage engine and Make autocommit as true in hibernate properties file.